# Getting access denied for site owner

Tags: 2013, permissions, sharepoint-on-prem

I am working with Share Point 2013 on prem. Users having site owner access are noticing weird issues right now. For example, if they go on the document library, upon clicking on 'permissions for this document library' option, they see 'Sorry you dont have access to this page', I have no idea why a site owner would see something like that.

If any one has come across this issue, please share your thoughts.Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check that user who is part of is part of site owner group has permission in **Master Page gallery** library. Give at least **read** permission.

If that doesn't fix the issue follow the below steps :

Go to the **Site Owner** group setting page.

From the **group setting** section, go to the "**Who can view the membership of this group**" change the radio button from **group members** to **everyone**.    Save the changes... now it should fix.